# oracle 19c - row count is different using 2 different users - why?

Tags: oracle, oracle19c, rowcount

Something very strange has happened since we migrated our schemas/database from 12c to 19c

When I insert records to a table and I check the row count
namely under my oracle user - say SMITH_J - I see 4 records. Good I am happy.

When my Java application looks at the same table which I will call QUEUE_TAB - using the application oracle user - say APP_TOMCAT - it just sees ZERO records. How can that be ?

I check the GRANTS for APP_TOMCAT - it has everything that should be there for that table - it's got SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE - which it had before.

What is really perplexing why are the record counts different - despite all the privileges being the same ? Is there something here that I have overlooked OR cannot see at the moment ? Is it something to do with privileges going from 12c to 19c ?

Comment: Assuming you committed the changes, and it isn't a temporary table... are you sure you and the application are actually looking at the same database and schema - the application doesn't still have the old connection details?

Comment: The other - albeit much less likely - possibility is the use of Virtual Private Database, which could make rows visible or invisible depending on the user. Hopefully you would know if you had that deployed in your database.

Comment: Just to test you are connecting to the same DB, can you rename the table from the environment where you insert 4 rows and see if from the Java environment you are getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I owe the correct answer to  [Alex Poole](https://stackexchange.com/users/98359) in the comments above.

I was using a procedure to populate the table in question. And, foolishly assumed that the procedure would commit it. Of, course, it would have if it DID have a COMMIT within the code at the end of the procedure. So, after EXECUTING the procedure - I issued a COMMIT and it worked.

It's best practice NOT to have a COMMIT statement within your procedure even if it is a single procedure. See the comments of @MTO and @Alex Poole below

Comment: It is correct not to have a `COMMIT` statement at the end of the procedure. If you do `COMMIT` at the end of each procedure call then it prevents you from chaining several procedures together into a single transaction and then issuing a `ROLLBACK` command on them all if something goes wrong with the last procedure call; instead you would only `ROLLBACK` to the last `COMMIT`. You should do what you have done and issue a `COMMIT` statement after you have run all the procedures.

Comment: Excellent point! Learn something every day. In this case however, it was a single procedure only. The reason why it did not "come to me" was because I rarely do update, insert via procedures. When, I do vanilla inserts, updates, it's easy to see that you need to commit after finishing - textbook stuff.

I kept running the procedure and wondering what was happening. It's like "pilot error" where like you can forget to put down landing gear - fortunately in modern planes - you are warned to do it. Or, you use a check list.
Oracle SQLDeveloper was d tool I used. Does TOAD remind u of COMMIT ?

Comment: You don't need to delete this, you can just accept your own answer. But I agree with MTO, you shouldn't commit inside a procedure, even if there is only one. Apart from anything else, there is only one procedure *today* - one day this might get called from another procedure, which won't be expecting a commit in the middle of what it is doing, and could cause rare, odd and hard to diagnose data issues. Better just to never do it, and explicitly commit in the outermost application/call.